# pass a php variable in an anchor tag inside a php loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a list of records on a table which look like this..

PHP/HTML CODE:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<?php
while($resrecord=mysqli_fetch_array($resdata))
{  ?>      
  <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $resrecord[0];?>  </td>
        <td> <?php echo $resrecord[2];?>  </td>
        <td> <?php echo $resrecord[3];?>   </td>
        <td> <a onclick="window.open('test.php?id='+'<?php echo $resrecord[0]; ?>','popup','width=600,height=600');">Tesing</a>  </td>
          //also checked with href of anchor tag
  </tr>
 <?php }   ?>
```

Which means I can't access a php variable in javascript. I also tried these methods

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var x= '<?php echo $resrecord[0]; ?>';  
  //OR
  var x= '<?php echo json_encode($resrecord[0]); ?>';
    //here x won't populate with above php variables
</script>
```

I've also tested the above javascript methods on a simple PHP variable which didn't belong to any loop and still didn't work.

Comment: The array may have 1000 rows .. which one you want to get in the javascript part ??

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki yeah but each row has anchor tag and will take that particular row when i click

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _will take that particular row when i click_, please describe more your need..

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki bro i think you didn't understood my question.. I've (say 5) rows in a table. So when i click on an anchor tag in third row, the resrecord[0] which is a serial number of that row, should be combined with a link to other page i.e test.php

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki  if I click on row 3 then that should open a popup link whose location will be ... test.php?id=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[UPDATED]** You can pass the value using attribute in a class, Try this one.

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<?php while($resrecord=mysqli_fetch_array($resdata))  {  ?>      
    <tr>
         <td> <?php echo $resrecord[0];?>  </td>
         <td> <?php echo $resrecord[2];?>  </td>
         <td> <?php echo $resrecord[3];?>   </td>
         <td> <a class="getAllData" data-id="<?php echo $resrecord[0];?>">Tesing</a> </td>
         //also checked with href of anchor tag
    </tr>
<?php }   ?>
```

Then use jquery function:

you do this.

```
<script>
    $(window).ready(function(){
        $(".getAllData").on("click", function(){
            var id = $(this).data('id'); //get the current data-id you the row
            window.open('test.php?id='+id,'popup','width=600,height=600');
        });
    });
</script>
```

This should do it.

Comment: Yup you can use `data` or `attr`. if you use `data` you can remove the `data-` when accessing it.

Comment: bro i think you didn't understood my question.. I've (say 5) rows in a table. So when i click on an anchor tag in third row, the resrecord[0] which is a serial number of that row, should be combined with a link to other page i.e test.php

Comment: if I click on row 3 then that should open a popup link whose location will be ... test.php?id=3

Comment: Im glad it helped. :)

Comment: btw.. in your script, you've used data('id'). what is the 'id' here. what it means here?

Comment: it is the data-id in your html when you use `data()` you will now delete the `data-` it is like the `attr` but `attr` is you will call it like this `$(this).attr('data-id');` but in the `data()` you can just write it like this `$(this).data('id')`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your variable value in JS, the best way is, keep you value in some element bonded with some selector  (keep it hidden if not required to display). Then use that selector to access the value.
eg.

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<?php
$i=0;
while($resrecord=mysqli_fetch_array($resdata))
{  $i++ ?>      
  <tr>
        <td><div class="hidden selector_<?php echo $i ?>">
               <?php echo $resrecord[0];?> 
            </div>
               <?php echo $resrecord[0];?> 
        </td>
        <td> <?php echo $resrecord[2];?>  </td>
        <td> <?php echo $resrecord[3];?>   </td>
        <td> <a onclick="window.open('test.php?id='+'<?php echo $resrecord[0]; ?>','popup','width=600,height=600');">Tesing</a>  </td>
          //also checked with href of anchor tag
  </tr>
 <?php }   ?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var x = $(".selector_1").val();
```

// you can iterate if required;
Hope you may get some idea with above example

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki  OP ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki : But v3.2.1 library is getting loaded, so we can use. and if not then we can use document.getElementsByClassName instead

Comment: @Arif Khan It's totaly unclear what you're trying to achieve.